# Error: Expression pattern of type 'CountableClosedRange<Int>' cannot match values of type 'UITextField!'

Tags: swift, switch-statement, uitextfield, case

I am getting the error stated above when I build and run this code in Swift. i am trying to make it so that the user can input a number and the switch statement will comeback  with the following print corresponding to that number.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var numberInput: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func inputText(_ sender: Any) {

        switch numberInput {

        case 0 ... 50:
            print("Number is between 0 & 50")
        case 51 ... 100:
            print("Number is between 51 & 100")
        case 101 ... 150:
            print("Number is between 101 & 150")
        default:
            print("Fallback option")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the Text from the textField, which is a String type, not a number. You have to convert it to a number first and then use it in a switch statement which takes cases of Integer range.

```
guard let text = numberInput?.text,let number = Int(text) else { return }
switch number {

    case 0 ... 50:
        print("Number is between 0 & 50")
    case 51 ... 100:
        print("Number is between 51 & 100")
    case 101 ... 150:
        print("Number is between 101 & 150")
    default:
        print("Fallback option")
    }
```

Comment: The problem is even more basic. The OP's code is trying to switch on an instance of `UITextField`, not even a `String`.